# componentsSeparatedByString - convert to array of NSMutableStrings

Tags: objective-c, string, tokenize

I know that you can use `NSMutableArray<NSString *> *myArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:mySeparator].mutableCopy` to create an `NSMutableArray<NSString *>` through the `componentsSeparatedByString` message.

Is there a way to create an `NSArray<NSMutableString *>` through `componentsSeparatedByString`?

Comment: You would have to do the method yourself.

Comment: It's dangerous to say "there's no way to do that" around here, but there's no way to do that.  It's easy enough to mutate the strings as you get them (and if needed, to reinsert into a mutable copy of the original array).